# Record of highest NF

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting, text

Using `awk` for the following input file, how could I take the record with highest `NF` for the same last field.

File:

```
5541,55004,919843,IND
5542,5541,55004,919843,IND
7903,790287,RUSE
7905,7903,790287,RUSE
```

Needed output:

```
5542,5541,55004,919843,IND
7905,7903,790287,RUSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage two arrays, one to keep the number of fields count, and one to keep the whole record, and the loop over the second array at the `END`:

```
awk -F, 'NF>a[$NF] {a[$NF]=NF; b[$NF]=$0} END{for (i in b) print b[i]}' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
5541,55004,919843,IND
5542,5541,55004,919843,IND
7903,790287,RUSE
7905,7903,790287,RUSE

% awk -F, 'NF>a[$NF] {a[$NF]=NF; b[$NF]=$0} END{for (i in b) print b[i]}' file.txt
5542,5541,55004,919843,IND
7905,7903,790287,RUSE
```